# Объект класса в качестве значения map

Tags: c++, map

Пытаюсь добавить в map элемент класса, выдает что нет подходящего конструктора. Вот пример кода (для примера взял структуру, но так же не работает и с классами). Если в качестве значения в map использовать базовый тип, то такой проблемы нету

```
struct Some {
    int value;
    explicit Some(int value) : value(value) {}
};

int main() {
    map<char, Some> list;
    Some x(10);
    list['z'] = x;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для использования типа данных `std::map` с оператором `[]` этот тип должен поддерживать инициализацию по умолчанию. Ваш класс ее не поддерживает, о чем вам и сказал компилятор.

Чтобы вставлять в `std::map` данные, не поддерживающие инициализацию по умолчанию, у вас есть

```
Some x(10);
list.emplace('z', x);
```

или даже сразу

```
list.emplace('z', 10);
```

А еще лучше, начиная с C++17

```
list.try_emplace('z', x);
list.try_emplace('y', 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
struct Some {
    int value;
    explicit Some(int value = 0) : value(value) {}
};
```

При обращении через оператор `[]` ему нужна возможность создания объекта по умолчанию - вот мы ее и предоставляем...

Или не пользуйтесь индексами, а вставляйте, скажем, так:

```
list.insert(make_pair('z',x));
```